# Trick for $\displaystyle\int\limits^{1}_{-1} \sin\left(x^3\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, analysis

I need to calculate $\displaystyle\int\limits^{1}_{-1} \sin\left(x^3\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$.
I know that generally the integral of $\sin(x^3)$ is hard to calculate using elementary methods, so I assume that must be some trick for calculating this on that bounds. Wolfram Alpha says that integral is 0, how to show that?
Anyone knows?

Comment: The sine function is odd.

Comment: Hint: $\sin(x)$ is odd, $x^3$ is odd, and the composition of two odd functions is odd.

Comment: @Batominovski, that's not enough, $sin(x^2)$ is even.

Comment: Well, so is that about making two integrals from this one (from -1 to 0 and from 0 to 1) and than showing somehow that one is equal to the other one * (-1)? I know that these functions are odd, but what exactly does it give when it comes to integrating those odd functions?

Comment: @piternet If $f$ is odd (and integrable on $[-a,a]$), then $\int_{-a}^a f = \int_{-a}^0 + \int_{0}^a f = 0$. This is because $$\int_{-a}^0 f(x)dx = -\int_{a}^0 f(-u)du =  \int_{0}^a f(-u)du=  -\int_{0}^a f(u)du$$ the last equality as $f$ is odd.

Comment: @GCab  It's a hint, not a solution.  As a hint, it should be sufficient.

Comment: @Batominovski, yes you are rigth, as a hint it was quite sufficient.

Comment: The antiderivative of an odd function is even. Then $F(1)-F(-1)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{-1}^1\sin(x^3)dx\underset{u=-x}=\int_1^{-1}\sin((-u)^3)(-du)=-\int_{-1}^1\sin(u^3)du=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

$$I =\int_{-1}^1\sin(x^3)\, dx = \int_{-1}^0\sin(x^3)\, dx + \int_{0}^1\sin(x^3)\, dx$$

In the penultimate integral, $x = -u\implies dx = -du$ so

$$I = \int_1^0 \sin(x^3)\, dx + \int_{0}^1\sin(x^3)\, dx = -\int_0^1 \sin(x^3)\, dx + \int_{0}^1\sin(x^3)\, dx = 0$$